# CSS positioning absolute causing elements to stack when not wanted

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have put together a simple Photo stack using CSS3 and JQuery. It works perfectly fine, but there is one major problem. The site needs to display out multiple stacks, an un-predictable amount due to the stacks being used to display a 'Photo gallery' on the website, and obviously the more galleries, the more stacks.

Without the stacks this is simple, just echo out an  tag with the src being retrieved from the DB. This is still simple when using the stacks as the only difference is a small piece of CSS and JQuery.

Now for the problem, I have used Absolute positioning to allow the three images in the stack to be erm, stacked. This is fine, but now when the stacks are echoed out, it's stacking the stacks, Urgh! So all i'm ending up with is one huge stack of images rather than separate single stacks on three images a piece.

Here is  the code.

```
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">

        #content {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width:  1024px;
        }

        #viewAlbumTitle {
            font-size: 20px;

        }

        #grid {

            line-height:          0;
            -webkit-column-count: 4;
            -webkit-column-gap:   10px;
            -moz-column-count:    4;
            -moz-column-gap:      10px;
            column-count:         4;
            column-gap:           10px;
        }

        #grid img {
            width:         100% !important;
            height:        auto !important;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding:       5px;
            cursor:        pointer;
        }

        @media (max-width: 480px) {

            #grid {
                -moz-column-count:    2;
                -webkit-column-count: 2;
                column-count:         2;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 320px) {
            #grid {
                -moz-column-count:    1;
                -webkit-column-count: 1;
                column-count:         1;
            }
        }

        .pv-div {
            padding: 0 0 4px 0;
        }

        .pv-link {
            font-size:       15px;
            color:           #000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .pv-link:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .thumb-over:hover {

        }

            /* image stsck */

        .image_stack {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .image_stack img {
            position:           absolute;
            border:             4px solid #FFF;
            box-shadow:         2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow:    2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            z-index:            9999;
            -moz-transition:    all 0.2s ease;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            -o-transition:      all 0.2s ease;
            transition:         all 0.2s ease;
        }

        .image_stack #photo1 {
            top:  8px;
            left: 108px;
        }

        .image_stack #photo2 {
            top:  6px;
            left: 104px;
        }

        .image_stack #photo3 {
            top:   4px;
            left:  100px;
            right: 100px;
        }

        .image_stack .rotate1 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
            -moz-transform:    rotate(15deg);
            transform:         rotate(15deg);
            -ms-transform:     rotate(15deg);
            -o-transform:      rotate(15deg);
        }

        .image_stack .rotate2 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -moz-transform:    rotate(0deg);
            transform:         rotate(0deg);
            -ms-transform:     rotate(0deg);
            -o-transform:      rotate(0deg);
        }

        .image_stack .rotate3 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
            -moz-transform:    rotate(-15deg);
            transform:         rotate(-15deg);
            -ms-transform:     rotate(-15deg);
            -o-transform:      rotate(-15deg);
            cursor:            pointer;
        }

        .stack_wrap {
            margin-left: -100px;

        }


    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".image_stack").delegate('img', 'mouseenter', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('stackphotos')) {//


                    var $parent = $(this).parent();
                    $parent.find('img#photo1').addClass('rotate1');
                    $parent.find('img#photo2').addClass('rotate2');
                    $parent.find('img#photo3').addClass('rotate3');
                    $parent.find('img#photo1').css("left", "150px");
                    $parent.find('img#photo3').css("left", "50px");


                }
            })
                .delegate('img', 'mouseleave', function () {
                    $('img#photo1').removeClass('rotate1');
                    $('img#photo2').removeClass('rotate2');
                    $('img#photo3').removeClass('rotate3');
                    $('img#photo1').css("left", "");
                    $('img#photo3').css("left", "");

                });
            ;
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- header -->
{include file="header.tpl"}
<!-- header end -->

<div id="content">

    <div style="margin:42px 0 0 -15px;">

        <div style="float:left; width:192px; padding:30px 24px 0 0;">
            <div>
                <span style="font-size:20px;">Username's photos</span>

                <div style="padding:10px 0 10px 0;"><img src="img/avatar.png" width="192"/></div>
                <div class="pv-div"><a class="pv-link" href="">Edit photo's</a></div>
                <div class="pv-div"><a class="pv-link" href="">Edit album</a></div>
                <div class="pv-div"><a class="pv-link" href="">Delete</a></div>
            </div>


        </div>


        <div style="float:left; border-left:1px solid #ebebeb; width:795px; min-height:400px; padding:32px 0 0 24px;">
            <!--<span>You currently have no pictures, why not upload some now?</span>-->

            <div>
                <span id="viewAlbumTitle">Username's photo albums</span>

                <div style="float:right"><a href="" class="main-button" onClick=('popUpload') style="margin:0;">upload
                    new pics</a></div>
            </div>

            <div style="margin:20px 0 0 0"></div>

            <div>

                <div style="margin:10px 0 0 0"></div>

                <div id="grid">

                    <div class="stack_wrap" style="float:left;">
                        <div class="image_stack" style="postion:relative;">
                            <img id="photo1" class="stackphotos" src="img/avatar.png">
                            <img id="photo2" class="stackphotos" src="img/avatar.png">
                            <img id="photo3" class="stackphotos" src="img/avatar.png">
                        </div>

                        <div class="image_stack" style="postion:relative;">
                            <img id="photo1" class="stackphotos" src="img/avatar.png">
                            <img id="photo2" class="stackphotos" src="img/avatar.png">
                            <img id="photo3" class="stackphotos" src="img/avatar.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width:100%; padding:10px 0 20px 0;">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
​
```

If any one could help me out it will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Jamie

Comment: Using the same ID multiple times in the same document is not allowed, and **will** cause problems. Use class names if you need to describe elements with similar meaning or function.

Answer (score 0):

Set the top position of the second stack.

```
<div class="image_stack" style="postion:relative;top:200px">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to want position:absolute for the container.

```
.image_stack { 
     position:absolute;   // this is wrong
}
```

for each image_stack that is position:absolute, each stack will to continue to stack on top of each other.  This is because position:absolute applies to its parent container where its default 0 0 axis starts.

**Here's what your CSS should read :**

```
.image_stack { 
     position:relative;  
}
.stackphotos{
   position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: this will allow your stack photos to be absolute positioned to the image_stack container

Comment: Downpour, doing that makes the whole thing vanish for some reason. That's the way i tried to do it before hitting here.

Comment: start adding some borders around your elements... border:1px solid red, border:1px solid green, so you can see where your elements are flying off to.

Answer (score 0):

Place each stack of three images in it's own container element:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="stack">
        <img src="img1" />
        <img src="img2" />
        <img src="img3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Set the stacks to float left:

```
.stack {
    float: left;
}
```

Set the images inside of the stack to be absolutely positioned:
    .stack img {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

Use jQuery to offset each image if you need to be able to see that there is more than 1 image in a stack:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".stack img").each(function(i, element) {
        var sibling = element.previousSibling;

        var top = 0;
        var left = 0;

        if (sibling) {
            top = $(sibling).position().top;
            left = $(sibling).position().left;
        }

        top += 5;
        left += 5;

        $(element).css("left", left);
        $(element).css("top", top);
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to make the whole thing act erratically :/

Comment: Still stuck with the same problem, however the images show in a different way also rather than neatly showing all 3, in a similar way to how you would fan out a deck of cards, they twist all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

i have tested the code and setting `position:relative` on `image_stack` class worked.
NB: dont forget to add `!important`

```
.image_stack{position:relative !important}
```

you can also set the z-index